# Bash Script Printing Output Twice

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following script which runs commands on each file in a directory to match for a specific pattern. It then prints the matching output to a .csv. I have the desired formatting, however each pattern that I am matching on is getting printed twice. Like this:

```
Match1
Match2
Match1
Match2
```

Piping uniq and sort into this script is not fixing the problem so I suspect my syntax is off. I have not been able to find a solution via Google or other answers thus far. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILES=/Users/User1/Desktop/Folder/"*"
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  # take action on each file. $f store current file name

    sed -n /"New Filters"/,/"Modified Filters"/p "$f" | grep -v -e 'Bugtraq ID:' 
  -e 'Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures:' -e 'Android' | grep -E '(^|[^0-9]) 
  [0-9]{5}($|[^0-9])'| sed 's/:/,/1' >> NewFile.csv

   echo "Complete. Check NewFile.csv"
 done;
```

***Sample Input: Expected Result is to extract text in bold***

> Filters
>   New Filters
>   Modified Filters (logic changes)
>   Modified
>   Filters (metadata changes only)
>   Removed Filters
>
> Filters
>   New Filters:
>   **29722: HTTP: Dragonfly Backdoor.Goodor Go Implant CnC Beacon 1**
>
> Modified Filters (logic changes):
>   Text I don't want
>
> Modified Filters (metadata changes only):
>   Text I don't want

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help a lot if you also posted some sample data, so we don't have to try to reverse-engineer them from your code. Without a way to quickly test what's happening, most potential answerers will not even bother trying to decipher it.

Answer (score 2):

We can't tell what your problem is without sample input/output so this isn't an answer to that, but here's how to really do what you're trying to do with that script:

```
awk '
FNR==1 { printf "Processing %s file...\n", FILENAME | "cat>&2" }
/"New Filters"/ { inBlock=1 }
inBlock {
    if ( !/Bugtraq ID:|Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures:|Android/ &&
             /(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{5}($|[^0-9])/ ) {
        sub(/:/,",")
        print
    }
}
/"Modified Filters"/ { inBlock=0 }
' /Users/User1/Desktop/Folder/"*" > "NewFile.csv"
echo "Complete. Check NewFile.csv"
```

Note that there's no shell loop required. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Any time you find yourself using multiple commands (in particular multiple seds and/or greps) and pipes just to manipulate text, consider just using awk instead.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the script twice? It appends with `>> NewFile.csv` without truncating the file at the beginning, so if run twice the CSV file would end up with repeated output. You can add `> NewFile.csv` at the beginning to empty out the output file.

Or, perhaps you have duplicate input files.

Comment: I'm running the script once on two files. I tested again by running on a single file and am still getting duplicates. Where exactly do you recommend adding `> NewFile.csv` to?

Comment: Why not simply show us the file so we can help you? Right now it's like you're asking a mechanic to diagnose a problem with your car but only letting him see half the car. See [ask] if that's not clear and in particular pay attention to the part about creating a [mcve].

Comment: Put `> NewFile.csv` on its own line. It's a standalone command that will truncate the file.

Comment: Thank you all for the input. I've added sample input and what I am aiming to extract. While going through the file I found that "New Filters" and "Modified Filters" was mentioned more than once. I believe I need to specify with the first sed command to grab the text between the 2nd match of "New Filters and 2nd of "Modified Filters".

Comment: The way to format input, output, and code in questions and answers is by indenting it 4 spaces (the editors `{}` button will do that for you), not by placing a `>` at the start of each line. Though the results look similar in the forum, the former gives us something we can simply copy/paste for testing with while the latter would require us to edit to remove the `>`s which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

if you need:

- extract anything between

  - *New Filter* ... *Modified Filters*
- but exclude

  - *Bugtraq ID:*
  - *Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures:*
  - *Android*
- also match

  - 5 digits up to 1 digit at the end
- plus

  - replace the first `:` with `,`

then you can try

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{$/=undef} push @r,$& while /(?<=New Filters).*?(?=Modified Filters)/gs; @r2=grep(!/Bugtraq ID:|Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures:|Android/g,@r); /\d{5}[^\n]+\d/g && ($_=$&) && s/:/,/ && print for @r2' file
```

for this sample input file

```
dified Filters (logic changes)   
Modified  
Filters (metadata changes only)   
Removed Filters  

Filters     
New Filters:  
29722: HTTP: Dragonfly Backdoor.Goodor Go Implant CnC Beacon 1  

Modified Filters (logic changes):   
Text I don't want  

Modified Filters (metadata changes only):   
Text I don't want  


New Filters:  
Bugtraq ID:

Modified Filters (logic changes):   


New Filters:  
Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures:


Modified Filters (logic changes):   


New Filters:  
Android
Modified Filters (logic changes):   


New Filters:  

29723: HTTP: Dragonfly Backdoor.Goodor Go Implant CnC Beacon 1  
Modified Filters (logic changes):   


New Filters:  

29724: HTTP: Dragonfly Backdoor.Goodor Go Implant CnC Beacon 1  

Modified Filters (logic changes):
```

output will be:

```
29722, HTTP: Dragonfly Backdoor.Goodor Go Implant CnC Beacon 1
29723, HTTP: Dragonfly Backdoor.Goodor Go Implant CnC Beacon 1
29724, HTTP: Dragonfly Backdoor.Goodor Go Implant CnC Beacon 1
```

Comment: @Nick otherwise tell me so I will delete the answer